# Datatable Server-Side Posting Undefined Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using the server-side processing post method to fill the data table with invoice transaction using json data object. It works as expected however I'm getting an Undefined error to read the key values of **header** sub elements.

JS

```js
var $jdatatable = $('#datatable_Invoice').DataTable({
      'info': false,
      'searching': true, //enable client side search. Link to DataTable()
      'lengthChange': false,              
      "ordering": false,
      'pageLength': 25,
      cache:false,
      'ajax': {
          url: 'ctrl/invoice_ctrl.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType:"json",
          render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text() , //XSS protect
          data: {
              'a': 'SEARCH',
              'txID': $(this).attr('data-id'),
          } //data

      } ,"drawCallback": function(jData) { // callback after table drawing
        console.log ( jData.header ) ;  //Error: undefined

        $('#inputCustomer').val( jData.AccountFull);    //Error: undefined

          $('.dt-buttons').hide();
        $('.data-table th').removeClass('sorting_asc');
        
      }
  });
```

Payload
[image]

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).